# Force Orchard repository to insert the data

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orchardcms

while the session is on . when calling an action i'm inserting some data in the database which i can work with later using other actions everything is fine .

The repository is getting the data and all good but once the session is terminated the data is not inserted in the database even tho while the session was on the repository was retreiving the data sucessfuly .

how to force the repository in orchard to insert the data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An explicit **sync** operation between DB and NHibernate `ISession` could be forced by explicit call: `session.Flush()`. The documentation:

#### [9.6. Flush](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-flushing)

small cites:

> ...
>
> From time to time the ISession will execute the SQL statements needed
>   to synchronize the ADO.NET connection's state with the state of
>   objects held in memory. This process, flush, occurs by default at the
>   following points
>
> ...
>
> Except when you explicitly **`Flush()`**, there are absolutely no guarantees about when the Session executes the ADO.NET calls, only the order in which they are executed. However, NHibernate does guarantee that the queries methods will never return stale data; nor will they return the wrong data.

In orchard, the repository implementation wraps that call:

[Repository.cs](https://github.com/ucdavis/Orchard/blob/master/src/Orchard/Data/Repository.cs#L117), at line 117

```
public virtual void Flush() {
    Session.Flush();
}
```

therefore, we can do the same

```
var repo = ... // get repository
repo.Flush();
```

that will sync the app and DB, i.e. all INSERT statements will be executed.